# Valgrind time limit

Tags: linux, valgrind, jenkins-plugins

I have an embedded system that runs indefinitely, and need to check it for memory leaks.  In a terminal it's easy enough to just kill the process, however, I need to set this up as an automatic thing on a Jenkins build server.  I have been unable to find a time limit option myself, so does anyone else know of a way for me to do this?

I am using the Jenkins Valgrind Plugin found here:
https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Valgrind+Plugin

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After pouring through the `valgrind` manual, there is no built-in time limit option.

However, if you want to do something like this, you can use `--trace-children` and build a wrapper/helper program that will fork the target program and then kill the fork after the time limit.